# Why is Blender 2.8 slower than older versions?

Tags: rendering, performance

I've been designing a car in blender, and getting a good image or animation takes hours. Then I heard 2.8 was out and that it cuts render times down significantly. So I installed it and I found that it was really slow, wireframe mode was buggy and the new engine, Eevee, was better but rendering was worse, nearly impossible.
Is the problem with 2.8 or maybe my computer. 
I've got a Mac mini, 2.3GHz Intel Core i5 with 8GB 1333MHz DDR3 RAM
My mate who has a Apple laptop has worse specs but can smoothly run it.

Answer (score 2):

Eevee is used as a "quick preview" of sorts for your render. That way you don't have to wait for Cycles to sample before you can actually see your render in full detail; Eevee is real-time.

As for your main question, have you tried un-installing Blender altogether, and re-installing the latest version of 2.8?

If you have, it might be that you have 8GB of RAM and an i5 CPU. These are not the best performance-wise.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Blender but it was still slow. I'm going to save up for a 3.2 GHz i7 CPU with 32GB of DDR4 RAM computer and continue to use the older version for now, but thanks for the comment

Comment: Don’t get your hopes up. I have Dell XPS 15-7590 (i9 / 4K OLED / 2TB SSD / 32GB RAM) with a powerful GPU, and Blender 2.8 is still slow. When I watch Blender Guru, his computer seems to handle Blender, easily.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson that is because Blender Guru either has 2+ GPUs linked in his computer, or he has the best you can buy (since he is monetized on youtube). Rendering is highly rigorous on whichever hardware you use, gpu or cpu. The more CPU cores you have, the faster you render; conversely, the more GPU vRAM you have, the faster you render.